# Adding margin to a div with an overflowing child

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm having an issue where I'm trying to add a bottom margin to a div that has a child overflowing the height. Dom elements fall right underneath the parent div while being covered by the child div, but I want dom elements to fall underneath the child div. The design that I'm looking for looks like such:

```
------------------------------
|                             |
|          Parent             |
|  -------------------------  |
|__|_______________________|__|
   |                       |
   |       child           |
   |_______________________|
 /* ------margin -------- */
 content
```

I've tried adding another div surrounding the entire thing with `height: fit-content`, but that only makes the height equal to the parent div, not including the child div. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: give parent margin-bottom of (child height - overlapping part) if child is 150px and the overlap part is 50px. give parent margin-bottom: 100px;

Comment: unfortunately, i don't know the heights of the child, they're images that are scaled according to their width. If I would I could manually put in a margin at the bottom

Comment: You can get the child height with js. Then use it to set the parent margin bottom to it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this without changing your structure. Basically, this is what "overflow" means.

I'd try to make your "parent" and "child" siblings inside a common parent. Position them similarly as you have it now, without overflow. Then, the content under it will be aligned properly and you can use a margin.

Something like this (paddings are not relevant, just for illustration):

```css
#new-parent {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

#old-parent {
  background: orange;
  padding: 2rem;
}

#old-child {
  background: lightblue;
  margin: -2rem 2rem 0 2rem;
  padding: 3rem;
}

#content {
  background: lightgray;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="new-parent">
  <div id="old-parent">
    old-parent
  </div>
  <div id="old-child">
    old-child
  </div>
</div>

<div id="content">
  rest of the content
</div>
```